# Shortcode (caption thumbnails) in post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress with the colornews pro theme. I would like to include photo caption in every post, under the main picture. I found something like that, but I do not know how and where to add it:

```php
<?php echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt; ?>
```

Comment: Add it in template code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pretty simple fix actually! From the [developer's website](https://themegrill.com/support-forum/topic/image-metadata/#post-1284663):

```php
<?php 
  the_post_thumbnail(); 
  echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt; 
?>
```

It seems that the only thing you're missing is `the_post_thumbnail();`

Comment: Thanks! 
However, I do not need ```the_post_thumbnail();``` because it displays the image twice. But, on the website you have linked I found the file to which I had to paste it. I just put it in the wrong file... thanks ;)